# Proving the existence of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ if $|f'(x)|≤(x^2+1)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I was trying to solve an exercise but got stuck. Maybe someone has a little hint for me.

**Task:**
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f'$ is continuous and
$$|f'(x)| \leq (x^2+1)^{-1}$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists.

**My Attempt:**
I figured since $f'$ is continuous and bounded by $1$ we could take the integral and get
$$\int|f'(x)|dx \leq \int (x^2+1)^{-1} = \arctan(x) + \tilde{C}$$
and conclude with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that
$$|f(x)| \leq \arctan(x) + C$$
for fixed $\tilde{C}, C \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ we now know that $f(x)$ is bounded if we choose $x$ to be over a certain boundry. Furthermore we know that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$.

Am I on the right track? What am I missing?

**PS:** I also thought about using the fact that $f'(x) = O(x^{-2})$ for $x \to \infty$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For $x>0$, you can write $$
f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x {f'(t)dt}. 
$$ Show that $\mathop {\lim }_{x \to  + \infty } \int_0^x {f'(t)dt}$ exists and is finite.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!